# How to modify the sieve approach to count the factors of a number less than a given n?

Tags: algorithm, factors

Okay so I'm trying find the factors of a number in time better than O(sqrt(n)) which made me look up the Sieve approach. Now I'm trying to find the factors of that number that is less than a given n(n<=number). Here's what I tried:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#define lli long long int

using namespace std;

const int Max=1000001;

lli prime[Max];

void sieveGen()
{
    prime[0]=0;
    prime[1]=1;

    for(lli i=2;i<Max;i++)
    {
        prime[i]=i;
    }
    for(lli i=4;i<Max;i+=2)
    {
        prime[i]=2;
    }

    for(lli i=3;i<Max;i++)
    {
        if(prime[i]==i)
        {
            if(i*i>Max)
            {
                break;
            }
            for(lli j=i*i;j<Max;j+=i)
            {

                if(prime[j]==j)
                {
                    prime[j]=i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


lli count_factors(lli num,lli i)
{
    if(i==2)
    return 1;
    
    
    if(i==3)
    {
        if(num%2==0)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    lli ans=1;
    
    lli count=1;
    lli first_prime=prime[num];
    lli second_prime=num/prime[num];
    
    
    while(second_prime!=1&&firstprime<i)
    {
        if(prime[second_prime]==first_prime)
        {
            count++;

        }
        else
        {
            first_prime=prime[second_prime];
            ans=ans*(count+1);
            count=1;
        }
        second_prime=second_prime/prime[second_prime];
        if(first_prime<i)
        {
            ans=ans*(count+1);
        }
    }
   
    return ans;
}

int main() {

    sieveGen();
    
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        lli N,M,res=0;
        cin>>N>>M;
        
        if(M==1)
        {
            res+=N-1;
        }
        else
        {
           for(lli i=2;i<=N;i++)
           {
               lli num=M-(M%i);
               if(num>0)
               {
                  cout<<i<<"."<<count_factors(num,i)<<"\n";
                  res+=count_factors(num,i); 
               }
               else
               {
                   res+=(i-1);
               }
           }
        }
       
      cout<<res<<"\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I want to find the number of factors of `num` that are less than `i`.

This is working fine for any prime `i` but fails for some other numbers like 6.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you call this function? What is `prime`?

Comment: I edited the post with the full code. ```prime``` is sieve of of all the smallest prime factor of a number.

Comment: Then why `prime[1]=1`? 1 is not a prime...

Comment: SInce we are running the code from 2 to N, ```prime[1]``` is never encountered. I just kept it like that.

Comment: I don't get the logic, `first_prime=prime[second_prime]` seems a complex way to say `first_prime=second_prime`  and `second_prime=second_prime/prime[second_prime]` is a complex way to say `second_prime=1`. Can you describe the algorithm you had in mind?

Comment: I don't think you know about the sieve approach of finding factors. The algorithm finds the frequency of distinct primes. The number of factors of the number are found by ```n= (1+a1)*(1+a2)*...```

Comment: Well, *that* is a good algorithm, but it is not what your code is doing. But since you think you know this algorithm better than me, I will leave you to it and will not bother you with my ignorance.

Comment: ```a1```, ```a2```,```...``` are distinct primes.

Comment: How so? I've successfully found all the factors of a number but the problem is I want to find the factors less than a given ```i``` which is why I modified the code but it didn't work

Comment: Do you agree that if `second_prime` is really prime, that then `prime[second_prime]` is equal to `second_prime`?

Comment: Yes ofcourse....

Comment: So then what does `second_prime=second_prime/prime[second_prime]` do?

Comment: Prime factorise the number? Hence when it gets to 1 we know that no more prime factorisation of the number is possible

Comment: Do you see any possibility for that assignment to be anything else than 1?

Comment: If ```num```=100 then ```secondprime```= 50. After first iteration ```secondprime```=25?

Comment: So `secondprime` is then a misleading name: it is not a prime then?

Comment: Uh yes, but what does it have to do with the algorithm or my original question anyways?

Comment: You have a small failing input 6. So start debugging and compare what the algorithm does with what you expected.

Comment: You run the Sieve of Eratosthenes for a pretty large constant to begin, so you can modify the sieve code (in-place) so that the data structure that would normally check for primality stores the prime factors along with the frequency in a map. So something that is prime, like 3, would have `primes[3] = {3 : 1}` while something composite like 12 would have `primes[12] = {2 : 2, 3 : 1}`. An entry would be prime iff its map contains one element, whose count is 1. From there, querying the prime factors less than i can be done in log(# unique factors) time, if you add a simple change to the map.

Comment: why not use the SoE to store the number of factors directly? simply forget about primes and increment every multiple of every number between `2` and `n` ... beware your LUT must contain also even numbers! The init will be slow but from that point any query up to `n` is just `O(1)` ... If you still want to go with prime decomposition first and then convert that to all possible combinations IIRC there wwas an FFT approach for that but it will be a lot slower than `O(1)` SoE LUT ... its more suitable for bignums where LUT will not fit into memory ...

Comment: @Spektre  Say I want to find the factors of 12 upto 6 how would that work?

Answer (score 0):

SoE for number for dividers is like this:

1. **init `SoE[n]` array**

   so allocate and clear with `0` the 1D array of integers of size `n` where `n-1` is the max value you want to query.
2. **for each number `i` from `2` to `n-1` compute SoE**

   so simply increment all `SoE[j]` where `j=i,2*i,3*i,4*i,...`
3. **now `SoE[x]` holds the number of dividers of `x`**

   its not accounting `1` but its accounting `i` so if you want not to just use decremented value.

Your for n=13 example would SoE look like this:

```
x | SoE[x]
--+-------
1 | 0
2 | 1
3 | 1
4 | 2
5 | 1
6 | 3
7 | 1
8 | 3
9 | 2
10| 3
11| 1
12| 5
```

so for `x=12` the `SoE[12]=5` and if you do not want to account x itself use `5-1=4` dividers `(2,3,4,6)`.

In case you also want the dividers itself (not just their count) then you can store the list of all numbers that divide instead of count in the SoE

```
x | SoE[x]
--+-------
1 | 
2 | 2
3 | 3
4 | 2,4
5 | 5
6 | 2,3,6
7 | 7
8 | 2,4,8
9 | 3,9
10| 2,5,10
11| 11
12| 2,3,4,6,12
```

again you can ignore the last element in `SoE[x]` list if you do not want to account `x` itself.

Prime decomposition is almost the same as this except you use only primes as `i` in the bullet **#2**.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I think the best way would be to create an array of maps. The ith cell of the array will represent the ith number. The map will have keys that are factors of the number and each time a number is a factor it will store the value of the previous key+1. So 12 will look like this: ```{{2:1, 3:2, 4:3, 6:4}}```